# mysql is not picking up the my.cnf in linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have got an environment with in Linux with mysql 5.5 + wordpress + php 5.6 + phpmyadmin
I have found out that no matter what value of system variable / option changed in the phpmyadmin will be reset after service / server restart
Also, none of the options in the /etc/my.cnf is being picked up
How would I be possible to resolve this problem?

location of my.cnf = /etc/my.cnf

mysql datadir = /var/lib/mysql

Comment: I would first copy the my.cnf to /var/lib/mysql..then using the ln command `ln [OPTION]... TARGET [...] [LINKNAME [...]]`... `sudo ln -s /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf`...